# Test NG - pass parameter with setTestClasses()

Tags: java, class, parameters, testng

I'm using the programmatically approach to run tests included in the Courier class.

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Courier.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

How is it possible to pass parameter to tests included in this class?
e.g.

```
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Courier("parameter").class });
```

Courier:

```
public class Courier {
@Parameter(passed parameter)
@Test
public void Courier_Test(String parameter){
    System.out.println(parameter);
}
```

}

Thanky for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

Even if you are running the tests programmatically, you should be able to invoke TestNG on a `testng.xml` file. Add parameters to the file like so (from the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)):

> ```
> <suite name="My suite">
>    <parameter name="parameter"  value="Foo"/>
>    <test name="Courier Test" />
>    < ... >
> ```

If for some reason you aren't using a testng.xml file, you can use a DataProvider, either as a method within the test class or as a static class, depending on what you need to do. Examples below (also from the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)).

DataProvider inside the class:

```
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares
//that its Data Provider is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
   return new Object[][] {
     new Object[] { "Parameter" }
   }
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied 
//by the Data Providernamed "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void Courier_Test(String parameter) {
 System.out.println(parameter);
}
```

DataProvider in external class:

```
public static class StaticProvider {
  @DataProvider(name = "create")
  public static Object[][] createData() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { "Parameter" }
    }
  }
}

public class Courier {
  @Test(dataProvider = "create", dataProviderClass = StaticProvider.class)
  public void Courier_Test(String parameter) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: These are all correct suggestions. Note that if you want to go the testng.xml route, you can create this file in memory (look up the Javadoc for XmlSuite, XmlTest, etc...).